# How can I install libsdl-ttf2.0:i386 without nuking my system?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to play Toribash, and after regularly installing all of the required libraries, I decided to try the `i386` ones and they solved the problems.
Until I got to `libsdl-ttf2.0`.
Trying to install `libsdl-ttf2.0:i386` results in this:

```
(precise)yungdavinci@localhost:~/Programs/toribash-3.24$ sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386' for regex 'libsdl-ttf2.0'
Note, selecting 'libsdl-ttf2.0-dev:i386' for regex 'libsdl-ttf2.0'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 gedit-common libgtksourceview-3.0-0 laptop-detect
  gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 xterm ubuntu-extras-keyring gir1.2-gtk-2.0
  gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico libpcrecpp0 xinput xbitmaps
  libtinfo-dev gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 libdrm-dev x11-xfs-utils
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common apport-symptoms zlib1g-dev xinit ubuntu-mono
  libfs6 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 libutempter0 gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0
  libjs-jquery adium-theme-ubuntu dmidecode
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libasound2-dev:i386 libavahi-client-dev:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common-dev:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libc6-dev:i386 libcaca-dev:i386 libdbus-1-dev:i386 libdrm-dev:i386
  libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-dev:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
  libglu1-mesa-dev:i386 libice-dev:i386 libice6:i386 libncurses5:i386
  libncurses5-dev:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpcre3-dev:i386 libpcrecpp0:i386
  libpng12-dev:i386 libpthread-stubs0:i386 libpthread-stubs0-dev:i386
  libpulse-dev:i386 libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libsdl1.2-dev:i386
  libselinux1:i386 libslang2-dev:i386 libsm-dev:i386 libsm6:i386
  libtinfo-dev:i386 libuuid1:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libx11-doc libxau-dev:i386
  libxcb1-dev:i386 libxdmcp-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxt-dev:i386
  libxt6:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386 mesa-common-dev:i386 python3 python3-minimal
  python3.2 python3.2-minimal uuid-runtime zlib1g-dev:i386
Suggested packages:
  libasound2-doc:i386 glibc-doc:i386 manpages-dev:i386 libglib2.0-doc:i386
  ncurses-doc:i386 libxcb-doc:i386 python3-doc python3-tk python3.2-doc
  binfmt-support
Recommended packages:
  gcc:i386 c-compiler:i386 python:i386 uuid-runtime:i386 libx11-doc:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apport apport-gtk apt-xapian-index aptdaemon compiz compiz-gnome
  compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf cpp
  evolution-data-server firefox foomatic-db-compressed-ppds gcc gcc-multilib
  gconf2 gdb gdebi gdebi-core gedit gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gksu
  gnome-control-center gnome-menus gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data
  indicator-datetime indicator-power launchpad-integration libasound2-dev
  libavahi-client-dev libavahi-common-dev libcaca-dev libcanberra-gtk-module
  libcanberra-gtk3-module libcompizconfig0 libdbus-1-dev libfreetype6-dev
  libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgnome2-common
  libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libice-dev libmetacity-private0
  libncurses5-dev libpcre3-dev libpeas-1.0-0 libpng12-dev libpulse-dev
  libpython2.7 librhythmbox-core5 libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev
  libslang2-dev libsm-dev libxext-dev libxt-dev light-themes lsb-release
  mesa-common-dev metacity metacity-common oneconf python python-apport
  python-apt python-apt-common python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python-aptdaemon.pkcompat python-cairo python-chardet python-crypto
  python-cups python-cupshelpers python-dbus python-debian python-debtagshw
  python-defer python-dirspec python-gconf python-gi python-gi-cairo
  python-gnomekeyring python-gnupginterface python-gobject python-gobject-2
  python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-httplib2 python-imaging python-keyring
  python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-libxml2
  python-mako python-markupsafe python-minimal python-notify python-oauth
  python-openssl python-packagekit python-pam python-piston-mini-client
  python-pkg-resources python-problem-report python-pycurl python-serial
  python-simplejson python-smbc python-software-properties python-twisted-bin
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-ubuntu-sso-client
  python-wadllib python-xapian python-xdg python-zeitgeist
  python-zope.interface python2.7 python2.7-minimal rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
  rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone sessioninstaller software-center
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev ubuntu-artwork
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-system-service
  unattended-upgrades unity unity-2d unity-common unity-lens-applications
  unity-lens-video unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote
  update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common
  x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-xserver-utils xorg zeitgeist zeitgeist-core
  zeitgeist-datahub
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libasound2-dev:i386 libavahi-client-dev:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common-dev:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libc6-dev:i386 libcaca-dev:i386 libdbus-1-dev:i386 libdrm-dev:i386
  libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-dev:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
  libglu1-mesa-dev:i386 libice-dev:i386 libice6:i386 libncurses5:i386
  libncurses5-dev:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpcre3-dev:i386 libpcrecpp0:i386
  libpng12-dev:i386 libpthread-stubs0:i386 libpthread-stubs0-dev:i386
  libpulse-dev:i386 libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
  libsdl-ttf2.0-dev:i386 libsdl1.2-dev:i386 libselinux1:i386
  libslang2-dev:i386 libsm-dev:i386 libsm6:i386 libtinfo-dev:i386
  libuuid1:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libx11-doc libxau-dev:i386 libxcb1-dev:i386
  libxdmcp-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxt-dev:i386 libxt6:i386
  linux-libc-dev:i386 mesa-common-dev:i386 python3 python3-minimal python3.2
  python3.2-minimal uuid-runtime zlib1g-dev:i386
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  python-minimal python2.7-minimal (due to python-minimal)
0 upgraded, 55 newly installed, 164 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 154 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

I really don't want to murder my system. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the following commands to install the libs manually:

```
mkdir libs;cd libs
apt-get download libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
ar xvf *
tar xvf data*
sudo mv ./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/* /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
cd
rm -R ~/libs
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Can I do this with any package I'm having problems with?

Comment: @YungDaVinci not always. Most of the time, there are dependencies needed to install and run an application. However, you may be able to get away with doing things this way when it is a simple library like this that only installs one or two files. For the most part, this method is not recommended and should only be used as a last resort. This is basically a hack so don't make a habit of it unless you absolutely need to.